# Validating data and looping through NSSet

Tags: ios, core-data, predicate, foundation, nsset

I have a CoreData (SQLite) datamodel in xcode like so:

```
Friends Table
  email
  name
  username
  belongsToGroups

Groups Table
  title
  peopleInGroup
```

So the `belongsToGroups` and `peopleInGroups` is a many-to-many relationship with each other, both represented by `NSSet` in the code.

What do I use to query the `NSSet` for people in my groups and vice versa? (I'm new to CoreData)

Comment: Query for what? What do you have to start with (a person / nothing?) and what are you trying to find?

Comment: I am trying to see if my person belongs to a group already, if not add him in, or ignore it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With coredata, you can do it simple. Assume we have one object on Groups Table ( group), you want to get all friends belong to group, you can do:

> [group. peopleInGroup allObjects]

For more detail:

1. Get group via title

> ```
> NSError* error = nil;
> NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
> NSPredicate *predicate;
> NSEntityDescription *entity;
> NSArray *fetchedObjects;    
> Group* group;    
> entity = [NSEntityDescription
>           entityForName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Group class]]
>           inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
> [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
> predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(title like[c] \"%@\")" ,title]];
> [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
> fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
> if (fetchedObjects.count > 0) {
>     group = [fetchedObjects lastObject];
> }
> return group;
> ```
>
> }

1. Get all friend of group

> NSMutableArray* friends = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>   [friends addObjectsFromArray:[group. peopleInGroup allObjects]];

Comment: don't you have to do an nsfetchrequest and all that first?

Comment: Yes, we need NSFetchRequest on group table via title, and then we get all member of group. Is it ok?